# Beamer Enumerate and Itemize

Tags: beamer

Is it possible to combine these environments? Now I have this code.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item b
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *combine*? You can nest them.

Comment: Combine in what way? Please make a _complete_ document that shows the problem. You can nest enumerate in itemize, or itemize in enumerate or do you mean some other combination?

Comment: Nesting these environments

Comment: @user29701, I suggest you to read the documentation of the `enumerate` package, which provides many ways to set up your lists.

Comment: @Sigur `beamer` does its own stuff with the standard lists, so packages like `enumerate` or `enumitem` won't preserve the `beamer` way of doing things.

Comment: The question is still terrible. The question itself does not even make sense. You had to take the title into account. Please consider extending the question -- I am sure this will stop the downvoting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

nesting?
if yes, then:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item b
   \begin{enumerate} 
   \item b 1 
   \item b 2 
   \item b 3 
   \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can pass options to each `\item`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\begin{itemize}
\item[1.] a
\item b
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: cool. have never seen that :-)

Comment: I did not mean that.

Comment: @user29701: Can you be more specific then?

Comment: @user29701 how can anyone know what you do mean from a single word "combine" ? Please edit the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the upvote :) Apparently the OP was looking for nesting the two environments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess nobody can know for sure, but a little bit text mining together with guessing leads to an answer. It would be too easy if a question would be clearly stated. ;-)